# Recovering from git reset --hard

Tags: git

I did (on master)

```
git branch mybranch
```

and then (still on master)

```
git reset --hard "commitid"
```

Now it seems I lost the commits after "commitid". Really? I lost it?

Is there anyway to recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checkout the new branch and the commits should be there

```
$ git checkout mybranch
```

This process is also useful when you want to move some recent commits to a new branch.

Comment: `checkout` won't reset `master` back to that commit.

Comment: @Kirill Of course not. But he didn't ask how to reset master, he asked how he could recover the commits

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use git reflog to find the point just before the git reset. Then you can use something like this

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are saved in the new branch you just created.

```
git reset --hard mybranch
```